# change invalid raw value in html input number via angular

Tags: javascript, angular, html-input

I'm using angular 4.0.0 and typescript. So let's say I have a .html file like this:

```
<input name="whatever"
[(ngModel)]="whatever"
type="number" (ngModelChange)="checkValue($event)">
```

I want to ensure that if invalid number is inputted, then the value displayed should revert to 0. Tried to do that using ngModelchange, where checkValue in .ts file is something like this:

```
checkValue(value: any) {
  console.log(value);
  if (!value) {this.whatever = 0;}
}
```

That doesn't work though.
when user type normally, everything is as expected. Type 123 and console will print 123
However when user copy paste / type invalid number (ex: 123ee), the console will print null. However, 123ee is still displayed in the html input. 
How do I clear the input? preferably via the 'angular' way